# WaitFor 2 different results in Karate tests

Tags: karate

We have a component which takes more time to build and we want to test it with Karate:

`retry(120, 1000).waitForText('h1', 'Successful')`

There can be more states in the h1 element (Waiting, Building), but error is usually shown almost immediately. How can we put waitForText to the condition and diferenciace between these 2 final states? Something like this

`retry(120, 1000).if (waitForText('h1', 'Successful')) { ...continue with tests } elseif(waitForText('h1', 'Error')) { karate.fail('Error occured') }`

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs for `optional()` and `exists()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#optional

Also it is quite likely `waitForAny()` will solve this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waitforany

```
* retry(120, 1000).waitForAny('{h1}Successful', '{h1}Error')
* if exists('{h1}Error') karate.fail('error occurred')
```

The first line above will actually return the `Element` so you can be smarter on the second line. There are many options, find the way that suits you best.